# How to retrieve files from a MongoDB database and display those files in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mongodb, electron

I'm a beginner with HTML, CSS, Javascript, Node.js and the Electron framework, and I'm trying to figure-out how to retrieve text files (from a MongoDB database via JS) and display those files in the desktop client. In the HTML file, the files should be displayed in the space under the comment "Files (residing in the database) should be displayed under here" (Although there are similar stackoverflow question, this question is about file retrieval, rather than file storage).

Below is the HTML file...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--This is the starting point of the desktop client development-->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Project Prime</title>

    <!--Linking the html file to the css file-->
    <link href="./index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--CSS file from Bootstrap website-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!--This form allows users to upload and delete files in the server-->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
            <h1 class="title display-4 my-4">Project Prime Desktop</h1>

            <!--Forms a connection to the server through HTTP POST request-->
            <form action="http://100.76.164.19:3003/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="custom-file mb-3">
                <input id="file" name="file" type="file" class="custom-file-input">
                <label for="file" class="custom-file-label">Choose File:</label>
              </div>

              <!--A button that inserts files into the server-->
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            </form>
            <hr>
            <!--Files (residing in the database) should be displayed under here -->













    <!--JS scripts from Bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is my JS file...

```
//Middleware between server and the routes

//Express for building APIs
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');

const app = express()

// Node.js built-in Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))

// To serve the static CSS file
app.use('/', express.static('./'))

// Mongo URI
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://projectPrime:projectPrime@projectprime-shard-00-00-wreg9.mongodb.net:27017,projectprime-shard-00-01-wreg9.mongodb.net:27017,projectprime-shard-00-02-wreg9.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=ProjectPrime-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true'
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);

// Create mongo connection
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
  // Init stream
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
})

// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({url: mongoURI,file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err)
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname)
        const fileInfo = {filename: filename, bucketName: 'uploads'}
        resolve(fileInfo)
      })
    })
  }
})
const upload = multer({storage});

// @route GET /
// @desc Loads homepage
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('src/upload.html', {root: __dirname});
})

// @route POST /upload
// @desc  Uploads file to DB
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
   // res.json({file: req.file});
   // Navigate back to the desktop client
   res.redirect('/');
})

// @route GET /files
// @desc  Display all files in JSON
app.get('/files', (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // Check if files exist
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'No files exist'
      });
    }

    // Files exist
    return res.json(files);
  });
});

// @route GET /files/:filename
// @desc  Display single file object
app.get('/files/:filename', (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.findOne({filename: req.params.filename}, (err, file) => {
    // Check if file
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'No file exists'
      });
    }
    // File exists
    return res.json(file)
  });
});

// @route DELETE /files/:id
// @desc  Delete file
app.delete('/files/:id', (req, res) => {
  gfs.remove({ _id: req.params.id, root: 'uploads' }, (err, gridStore) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(404).json({ err: err })
    }
    res.redirect('/')
  })
})

module.exports = app
```

**Attempted Solutions**

- After converting the HTML file into an EJS file, I wrote EJS  code to display the Mongo-stored files...

  ```
  <% if(files) { %>
            <% files.forEach(function() { %>
                <div class="card card-body mb-3">
                  <% if(file.isImage) { %>
                    <img src="image/<%= file.filename %>" alt="">
                  <% } else { %>
                    <%= file.filename %>
                  <% } %>
                  <form method="POST" action="/files/<%= file._id %>?_method=DELETE">

                    <!-- Removes files from the DB upon button press-->
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-4">Delete</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              <% }) %>
          <% } else { %> 
            <p>No files to show</p> 
          <% } %>
  ```

Comment: Your code is all calling `gfs.files.findOne()` which is just the file "metadata". The actual **binary** content comes from `gfs.createReadStream()` as demonstrated on the linked answer.

Comment: OK. But my question is about retrieving files from the Mongo database, rather than storing files, if that makes sense?

Comment: Read the actual answer and code instead of the question title of the duplicate. The examples show **BOTH** Reading and Writing.